# Filter models with created date less than today's date

Tags: python, django

So i have a model,  And i want to filter all models with created date less than today's date .

For example

```
Class Post(models.Model):
    created=model.DateField()
```

view.py

```
get_objects_with_date_lessthan_today_date=Post.objects.filter(created=)
```

In my view i need to filter all objects with created date less than today's date .Please i need help . In going about this logic

Answer (score 13):

Use the `__lt` (less than) [filter lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups):

```
from datetime import datetime

Post.objects.filter(created__lt=datetime.today())
```

Comment: What is the greater than filter function . are all these found in django documentations ? Thanks

Comment: See the documentation for [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for posts created earlier than today

```py
from datetime import date
Post.objects.filter(created__lte=date.today())
```

In case you want to include post's from today but earlier than right now use:

```py
from datetime import datetime
Post.objects.filter(created__lte=datetime.today())
```